# FirebaseCrashlytics: Create report HTTP request failed. okhttp3 timeout

Tags: android, firebase, okhttp, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

Crashlytics is failing to report fatal/non-fatal crashes due to a connection timeout issue.

This is my app-level build gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4'
```

Now the crashes are not being logged, and each time I open the app I'm getting this,

```
E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Create report HTTP request failed.
    java.io.InterruptedIOException: timeout
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.timeoutExit(Transmitter.kt:105)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.maybeReleaseConnection(Transmitter.kt:295)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.noMoreExchanges(Transmitter.kt:259)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.kt:202)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:67)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:129)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.network.DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.java:90)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.network.CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.java:34)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.ReportUploader.uploadReport(ReportUploader.java:116)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.ReportUploader$Worker.attemptUploadWithRetry(ReportUploader.java:194)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.ReportUploader$Worker.onRun(ReportUploader.java:149)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: Canceled
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:65)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.kt:194)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:67) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:129) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.network.DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.java:90) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.network.CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.java:34) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.ReportUploader.uploadReport(ReportUploader.java:116) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.ReportUploader$Worker.attemptUploadWithRetry(ReportUploader.java:194) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.ReportUploader$Worker.onRun(ReportUploader.java:149) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Error occurred sending report com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.model.SessionReport@8309e69
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.InterruptedIOException: timeout
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.network.DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.java:100)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.network.CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.java:34)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.ReportUploader.uploadReport(ReportUploader.java:116)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.ReportUploader$Worker.attemptUploadWithRetry(ReportUploader.java:194)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.ReportUploader$Worker.onRun(ReportUploader.java:149)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: timeout
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.timeoutExit(Transmitter.kt:105)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.maybeReleaseConnection(Transmitter.kt:295)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.noMoreExchanges(Transmitter.kt:259)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.kt:202)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:67)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:129)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.network.DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.java:90)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.network.CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.java:34) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.ReportUploader.uploadReport(ReportUploader.java:116) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.ReportUploader$Worker.attemptUploadWithRetry(ReportUploader.java:194) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.ReportUploader$Worker.onRun(ReportUploader.java:149) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: Canceled
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:65)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.kt:194)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:67) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:129) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.network.DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.java:90) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.network.CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.java:34) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.ReportUploader.uploadReport(ReportUploader.java:116) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.ReportUploader$Worker.attemptUploadWithRetry(ReportUploader.java:194) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.ReportUploader$Worker.onRun(ReportUploader.java:149) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Is it something wrong with crashlytics?

Comment: @Mkr just today or did you had this before?

Comment: Just today. What is strange, some crashes were uploaded successfully (I think this crashes which happend maybe..1-2 hours ago?) but I can't see rest sent recently. What's more interesitng, i something see info about "succesfully uploaded logs" in .logcat, but I cant see them in firebase console

Comment: To be more precise sometimes i got timeout and sometimes, I see this logs: Initializing Crashlytics 17.1.0
Crashlytics Reports Endpoint upload complete: <some long number>,  but I can't see crashes in console

Comment: Probably related to this ongoing incident: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Crashlytics/20004

Comment: hey, i am experiencing the same error today and there is no ongoing incident o firebase. i am not even using their crashlytics library.. my main issue is not the logs but being unable to see my okhttp client working. did something like that happened with you too?

Comment: @anshsachdeva There was a problem related to network calls with the Gradle plugin `4.0.x`. Try downgrading it to `3.6.4`.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala it could be, but my error went away when i changed my proguard rules to keep okhttp and gson source files. so there are multiple cases which could lead to this super vague error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is now fixed. The root cause for the issue was unknown. But as [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560358/) suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/111116885) it may be linked to the following incident which occurred on the same day.

- [Crashlytics Incident #20004](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Crashlytics/20004)

However, their logs did not specifically say that those two were related.

---

Anyway, my advice for future readers. If you have encountered this issue, visit below link to check the status of the `Crashlytics` itself, because there's a good chance that it may be one of their issues.

- [Firebase Status Dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/)<sup>*</sup>

<sup>*It may take a while for the status to get updated.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, that error is related to this incident, https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Crashlytics/20004, and can be tracked via that link.